# Dataframe merge and timeindex creating

Tags: pandas

data1 and data2 are two Dataframes which read data from two different csv files by pandas.

```
data1 = pd.read_csv(file1)
data2 = pd.read_csv(file2)
```

data1 has a time index column. Its format is as follows:

```
2016/6/11 1:00:00
2016/6/11 2:00:00
2016/6/11 3:00:00
The time interval is 1 hour.
```

data2 also has a time index column which is not irregular. Its format is as follows:

```
2016/6/11 1:15:00
2016/6/11 1:30:00
2016/6/11 2:45:00
2016/6/11 3:15:00
The time interval is 15minutes，however there are lots of missing datetime strings.
```

Now I want to supplement missing time indices in data2 from 2016-1-1 0:00:00 to 2017-4-1 0:00:00 with time interval 15 minutes，and using some techiques to create values for other columns of these created time indices（I'm very glad to accept your suggestions about any techiques）

At last, I need to merge the data with same time index in data1 and data2.
Could someone give me any instructions? Many thanks!

Comment: You can generate data2 in 15 minute intervals with `s = pd.date_range('2016-01-01', '2017-04-01', freq='15T', normalize=True).to_series()`

Comment: Thanks mate, I solved the problem with the hints you given me!